# Show that estimate is unbiased

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

**TASK:**

Suppose $X_i (i=1,2,3,…,n)$ are i.i.d random variables with PMF: $f(x, \theta ) = exp(\theta-x), x>\theta$.
Is the estimate unbiased: $\mu = \frac{1}{n} + $min$(X_i)$?

**Answer:**

First, we find the CDF for $\mu$: $F(x) = P(\mu < x) = P($min$(X_i) < x - \frac{1}{n}) = 1 - P($min$(X_i)\geq x - \frac{1}{n}) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i \geq x - \frac{1}{n}) =  1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1 - P(X_i < x - \frac{1}{n})) = [1]$.

Next: $P(X_i < x - \frac{1}{n}) = \int_{\theta}^{x-\frac{1}{n}} exp(\theta - x)dy = -exp(\theta - x + \frac{1}{n}) + 1$, so

$[1] = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+ exp(\theta - x + \frac{1}{n}) - 1) = 1 -exp(\theta * n - x * n + 1)$.

Now we find PMF for $ \mu: f(x) = F'(x) = n * exp(\theta * n - x * n +1)$.

**EDITED**:

We can find mean: $E(\mu) = \int_{\theta}^{+\infty}x * n * exp(\theta * n - x * n +1) dx = e * (\theta + \frac{1}{n})$

So mean with $f(x, \theta)$ is: $E(\theta) = \int_{\theta}^{+\infty}x * exp(\theta - x)dx = \theta + 1$.

Finally, $E(\mu) \neq E(\theta)$, so the estimate isn't unbiased.

*That's it?*

Thank you for any help.

Comment: are you sure it is $f_X(x | \theta) = e^{\theta - x} , x > 0$ and not  $f_X(x | \theta) = e^{\theta - x} , x > \theta$?

Comment: @daniel, yes, you're right. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by CDF for $\mu$. The mean, $\mu$ is a fixed value (once $\theta$ is fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an estimator is unbiased, we need to show that $\mathbb{E}(\mu)=\theta$, where $\mu$ is the estimator and $\theta$ is the parameter.

Let's call $Y:= \min(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.

$$
F_Y(y) = 1-P(X_1>y, \dots, X_n>y)=1-[1-F_X(y)]^n=1-e^{n(\theta - y)} \\
\Rightarrow f_Y(y) = ne^{n(\theta-y)}, \quad y>\theta
$$

The expectation then becomes:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\mu) = \frac{1}{n}+\int_{\theta}^{+\infty}y f_Y(y)dy = \frac{1}{n}+\theta +\frac{1}{n}=\frac{2}{n}+\theta \ne \theta
$$

hence $\mu$ is biased.